# how to ship a Django app as a docker image?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I would like to package and ship a Django web app as a Docker image.

When I do a docker-compose up, I see a tree hierarchy in Docker desktop containers and works as expected when I navigate to http://localhost:85

```
django-dashboard-volt
|___appseed_app
|___nginx
```

If I save and load the image, I see the following in the Docker desktop containers and the web application does not work:

```
django-dashboard-volt_appseed-app
nginx
```

Here's how I save and load the images:

```
docker save django-dashboard-volt_appseed-app:latest nginx:latest | gzip > django.tar.gz

docker load --input django.tar.gz
```

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY . .
ADD test .
ADD data .

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONPATH /test

ENV APP_USER=xxxx
ENV APP_HOME=/home/$APP_USER

# install python dependencies
#RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --upgrade pip 

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

RUN tar xvzf gurobi9.5.0_linux64.tar.gz
ENV GUROBI_HOME /gurobi950/linux64
RUN cd /gurobi950/linux64 && python setup.py install
RUN rm gurobi9.5.0_linux64.tar.gz
RUN echo "TOKENSERVER=xxxx" > /gurobi.lic

RUN groupadd -r $APP_USER && \
    useradd -r -g $APP_USER -d $APP_HOME -s /sbin/nologin -c "Docker image user" $APP_USER

    
ENV TZ 'America/Los_Angeles'
RUN echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y tzdata && \
    rm /etc/localtime && \
    ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \
    apt-get clean
        

RUN chown -R $APP_USER:$APP_USER /gurobi950
RUN chown -R  $APP_USER:$APP_USER  /db

### What is better than 777?
RUN chmod -R 777 /db
RUN chmod -R 777 /gurobi950

ENV GRB_LICENSE_FILE /gurobi.lic
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/gurobi950/linux64/lib
RUN /gurobi950/linux64/bin/gurobi_cl --version

WORKDIR /


# running migrations
RUN python manage.py migrate

USER $APP_USER

# gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--config", "gunicorn-cfg.py", "core.wsgi"]
```

My Question:

How should Django Docker image be saved and loaded so that the loaded Django container works from the web browser?

**docker-compose.yml for image creation**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  appseed-app:
    container_name: appseed_app
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    build: .
    networks:
      - db_network
      - web_network
    volumes:
      - ../hs:/hs
      - ../data:/data
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "85:85"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - web_network
    depends_on: 
      - appseed-app
networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
  web_network:
    driver: bridge
```

**docker-compose.yml for remote deployment from tar images**
(removed build:, copied nginx/, .env from original source)
(stopped all containers on the source machine itself and issued docker-compose up from a different directory containing the .yml, .env, nginx/. Instead of save/load images, did not remove original images from docker desktop on the source machine).

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  appseed-app:
    image: "django-dashboard-volt_appseed-app:latest"
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      - db_network
      - web_network
    volumes:
      - ../hs:/hs
      - ../data:/data
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:latest"
    restart: always
    image: "nginx:latest"
    ports:
      - "85:85"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - web_network
    depends_on: 
      - appseed-app
networks:
  db_network:
    driver: bridge
  web_network:
    driver: bridge
```

**Error on navigating to localhost:85**

This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

**log**

```
nginx_1        | 2022/01/18 21:00:33 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "appseed_app:5005" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/appseed-app.conf:2
nginx_1        | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream
```

**containers in docker desktop after deployment**

```
 django-dashboard-volt
    |___django-dashboard-volt_appseed_app   (running)
    |___django-dashboard-volt_nginx         (restarting)
```

Comment: `load` is not the same as `run`. Why are you expecting port 85 to do anything? Where are you forwarding this?

Comment: mmm...with docker-compose up, I did not do any port forwarding, but it works in the browser.  I did the "docker run" from the docker desktop UI using the Run button.

Comment: You shouldn't normally need `docker save`, unless you're in an isolated environment where it's literally impossible to access a Docker registry.  `docker push` (or `docker-compose push`) the built image(s) to a registry instead, and manually copy the `docker-compose.yml` file to the other system (without `build:` blocks).

Comment: @DavidMaze registry is ruled out for now. Could I save/load and copy over docker-compose.yml without build blocks? And possibly, remove container names and replace them with image names?

Comment: It might help to edit the question to include your `docker-compose.yml` file and a description of what goes wrong when you try to run the application on the target (air-gapped?) machine.  You can almost always delete `container_name:`, and yes, the Compose setup does need to name `image:`s for this case.

Comment: The compose file isn't the deployable unit. The containers individually are...  For compose `build` / `image` are mostly interchangeable. Please show your compose file. You need `ports` defined in the YAML for the port forwarding to work so that you can access the container from the host, including the browser

Comment: posted docker-compose.yml for source and remote

Comment: @DavidMaze any ideas?

Comment: @OneCricketeer any thoughts?

Comment: Well, your error is with Nginx, not Django. According to the error, your nginx config has `appseed_app:5005`, but underscores are not allowed in hostnames, and your container is actually `appseed-app`, as defined in the compose file... Secondly, you will want to `EXPOSE 5005` in your Django Dockerfile (assuming this is the actual port it starts on). I suggest commenting out Nginx from your YAML and add `ports: '5005:5005'`, and connect to `localhost:5005` if you want to test Django in isolation

Comment: @OneCricketeer ... that worked!

Comment: @OneCricketeer .. Is it safe to say:   when shipping docker image to others, remove nginx; and when hosting as a website without docker, include nginx ?